# How to reuse value of insert statment

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a SQL statement such that I'm reusing a return value of an insert statement as a value for following insert statement but I have no clue where to start. For example, this is my table schema (didn't write everything).

```
job {
job_id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
start_date, 
end_date, 
target hours,
worker_id 
FOREIGN KEY (worker_id) REFERENCES dbo.worker (worker_id)
}

worker {
worker_id INT IDENTITY (1, 1) PRIMARY KEY, 
name
}
```

And I want to do something like this but I don't think this is the right way to do it

```
 INSERT INTO dbo.job
    VALUES(GetDate(), NULL, 8, (
    INSERT INTO dbo.worker
    OUTPUT 
    Inserted.worker_id
    VALUES ('my_name')
    ))
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? And [insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @DaleK , I did take a look but i'm uncertain how to just return one value and reuse it. I was under the impression i should be returning a table instead of a single value and somehow use that...

Comment: A table can always cope with a single value... just copy one of the examples... or you can use [`scope_identity()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/scope-identity-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way for your matter is

```
DECLARE @worker_idtbl TABLE (worker_id INT);
INSERT INTO dbo.worker OUTPUT Inserted.worker_id INTO @worker_idtbl(worker_id) VALUES ('my_name');
INSERT INTO dbo.job VALUES(GetDate(), NULL, 8, (select top 1 worker_id from @worker_idtbl) );
```